# Invalid Menu Items

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, menus

I registered a taxonomy named districts, but when I add districts to nav menus, the nav menu items are invalid! Here is the code that registers the taxonomy:

```php
    function masallah() {

    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
    //first do the translations part for GUI

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Districts', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'District', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Districts' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Districts' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Districts' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent District:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit District' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update District' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New District' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic District' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Districts' ),
        );

    // Now register the taxonomy

        register_taxonomy('Districts',array('post'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'districts' ),
            'has_archive' => true,
        ));

    }

    add_action( 'init', 'masallah', 0 );
```

Comment: You need to write your question. You can't be asking questions with YouTube videos.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I dont know how to code videos, can I paste the code that comes from view button on winrar? Also I am not sure that you re-solve these code if you are not NEO from Matrix

Comment: Just describe the problem you're having! With words!

Comment: Questions **must** be self contained, if viewing the youtube video is necessary to even know what the question is then it will be closed as unclear what you're asking. It does not matter how effective or good the video is, the question must contain the question, in words, in english.

Comment: Having viewed the video, the only thing I can see wrong with your code is that you define `rewrite` twice, but that would not cause the problems you are seeing, and it would not cause a `000` taxonomy to appear. You need to switch to the default theme and disable all plugins, then re-enable them one by one to identify the plugin causing this, it is not standard WP behaviour. This also looks very familiar, did you ask this question using another account?

Comment: @TomJNowell I told on youtube video that you didnt it that disaple plugins.If it doesnt related the code, probably it depeneds database.Something registered wrong on database because of theme, then it gives error.so I need clear related tables/infos on database

Comment: No, it is not a database thing. Taxonomies are registered on each page, they aren't defined in the database. Again, do not explain with a youtube video, you MUST ask your question in text, in the question. I will now remove the youtube video, and close this as unclear what you're asking. Edit your question so it's clear what your question is and it can be reopened

Comment: @knockknock I believe i have found the source of your problem, and managed to reproduce it, but I need you to edit your question so that it contains the question. I believe your question is: "I registered a taxonomy named districts, but when I add districts to nav menus, the nav menu items are invalid! Here is the code that registers the taxonomy:", but I cannot be sure of this

Comment: Okay I will edit the question if you are not liar

Comment: @TomJNowell I changed it

Comment: Thanks! I made an adjustment or two and reopened

Comment: Please delete your menu items and re-assign then at Appereance > Menus and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified two issues, the first, this:

```php
            'rewrite' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'districts' ),
```

Can just be this:

```php
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'districts' ),
```

And the second, the reason you get invalid menu items, is because `districts` is being used as the rewrite slug, but, the internal namevof the taxonomy is `Districts`.

Replacing `Districts` with `districts` as the internal name fixed the issue for me locally:

```php
register_taxonomy( 'districts', array('post'), array(
```

It's a general rule of thumb to keep internal names of things lower case, you can always use the labels for what the user sees

Comment: you are right.thank you! I hope I will find you here if I get new error